# I am using Journal in the Paper environment but need to change format of \JournalContents. How do I do this?

Tags: macros, xetex, journal, paper

This is my main.tex document

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt]{paper}
\begin{document}
\journalcontents
\include{./paper_1}
\end{document}
```

The paper_1.tex document is as follows

```
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author name}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\shortauthor{Short author name}
\maketitle
```

The problem is that the \journalcontents macro prints the Short author name in bold and dots to the page number, and then on the next line it shows the short title for paper 1 and any other papers I include.This is shown here
[image]

What I want is for the  \journalcontents to print the Shorttitle then the dots to the line number with the Subtitle on the next line which can be multiple lines.

How do I edit the \journalcontents macro to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want. Because I am not familiar with the `paper` document. However by checking the source code, the `\journalcontents` entries are added though `\maketitle` command. You could patch the `\maketitle` command to have extra subtitle entry after the short title. I assume you want it to use the full text width and without any indent.

```
\documentclass[journal,12pt]{paper}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\if@twoside}{\addtocontents{jou}{\noindent\@subtitle\par}\if@twoside}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\journalcontents
\title{Title}
\subtitle{A super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super super Subtitle}
\author{Author name}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\shortauthor{Short author name}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. How can I remove the author names ? Also where can I find the \maketitle command. Maybe I can copy and amend and rename the paper.cls file ?

Comment: @Dom Yes, it is defined in the `paper.cls` file. You don't need to copy and edit the whole file. You just need to modify the `\maketitle` command definition as I did.

Comment: @Dom patch `\maketitle` command like this to get rid of author name. `\patchcmd{\maketitle}{{\sss@font\@shortauthor}\hfill\mbox{}\vskip\normallineskip}{}{}{}`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dom You're welcome. Unless you are not satisfied with the majority of the format in the class definition, some small tweaks can be made through patching command.